# Define EventHandler<EventArgs> In XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a problem defining an EventHandler in XAML. Please take a look at the code and you will understand what I am trying to do and how I am trying to assign a method in XAML or better said how I am defining the EventHandler in XAML.

This is code:

```
public static EventHandler<EventArgs> GetResetValue(DependencyObject obj)
{ 
   return (EventHandler<EventArgs>)obj.GetValue(ResetValueProperty);
}

public static void SetResetValue(DependencyObject obj, EventHandler<EventArgs> value)
{
    obj.SetValue(ResetValueProperty, value);
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ResetValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ResetValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ResetValue", typeof(EventHandler<EventArgs>), typeof(Extension), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnResetValue));

private static void OnResetValue(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    DependencyObject obj = dependencyObject;
    for (; obj != null && !(obj is TextBox); obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj)) ;

    TextBoxtbx = obj as TextBox;
    if (tbx != null)
    {
        tbx.TextChanged += (EventHandler<EventArgs>)dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue;
    }
}
```

XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBox>
 <Button>
  <Label ext:Extension.ResetValue=".. here i want to assign the handler, as examle DoSomething" >
 </Button>
</TextBox>
```

The  method which i wish to assign to attached handler is inside Window.cs looks like this as example:

```
public void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ....
}
```

As you can see in OnResetValue method I travel up the VisualTree till i find the TextBox and I add the handler to TextBox.TextChanged event.

When TextChanged then the attached handler method will be called which will call the assigned method

The question is how do I define that attached hander in XAML with DoSomething method? Please no alternative solutions. I would like to do this with events if possible.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You've clearly made a serious attempt at a solution, but you need to say what's not working so people can help you.

Comment: I edited my question. The assigning is not working. Please read the very first sentence and you will know that I am having problems defining/setting/assigning a method on the attachedproperty handler of type EventHandler<EventArgs>. Also take a look at the xaml and you will see where I wish the method to be defined to attachedproperty handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the normal XAML mechanism for attaching event handlers:

```
<Button Click="OnButtonClick"/>
```

but in your case the thing you're trying to assign to is not an event, but a normal property which has a type that happens to be an EventHandler delegate. This might be more clear if you were to change the type of ResetValue to instead use `Action<object, EventArgs>` which would be functionally the same.

To expose your handler method in a form that can be assigned to your ResetValue property you can do something like this:

```
public EventHandler<EventArgs> DoSomethingMethod
{
    get { return new EventHandler<EventArgs>(DoSomething); }
}
```

Now that you have a property that matches the type of the DP you want to set you can just use a normal Binding:

```
<Label ext:Extension.ResetValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DoSomethingMethod}" >
```

Comment: As I said in the answer - your code is assigning to a delegate property, not an event.

Comment: How would it look alike with an event? I am seeking for attached event which is not routedevent.

Comment: Attached events are based on RoutedEvent so you can't separate the two.

Comment: Ok then can you show me how to attach an routed event which doesnt support bubbling or tunneling and once raised on element textbox the label, which is an element inside textbox as in my shown xaml, gets notfied and executes its attached handler?